# Uninformed search: run breadth-first search followed by iterative deepening search on each node in the frontier

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to combine breadth first search and iterative deepening search. This approach is mentioned in the AI book, AI - A modern approach, chapter 3 (pg. 90). The idea is starting from the initial state, run breadth-first search until some constant memory limit mB is reached, and then run iterative deepening search on each node in the frontier.

Is this search algorithm sound? Complete? Optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadth-First Search itself is sound, complete, and optimal. So, for any problem where the BFS already finds a solution before the memory limit is reached, there are no problems. We'll only have to consider what happens in the cases where the memory limit is reached before finding a solution, e.g. problems where you will start running IDS on nodes in the frontier:

**Sound?**

Yes, IDS will never somehow return a result that is not correct.

**Complete?**

This depends on how you implement "IDS on each node in the frontier".

If you first do a complete IDS on the first node in the frontier, then a complete IDS on the second node in the frontier, etc., it will not be complete. Consider the case where there is an infinitely-sized search space under the first node in your frontier, which does not contain the solution. If you try to run a "complete" IDS on that node first, it will never terminate.

However, if you spread out your IDS processes over the nodes in the frontier in a different manner, it can be complete. For instance, if you first do a DFS up to depth 1 for all nodes in the frontier, then a DFS up to depth 2 for all nodes in the frontier, etc., the algorithm will be complete.

**Optimal?**

The same counts here as for completeness. If you complete a full IDS for the first node in the frontier before moving on to the second node, you may have found a suboptimal solution below the first node in the frontier already, so the algorithm will be suboptimal.

If you complete DFS processes with a depth limit of 1 for all nodes in the frontier before moving on to a DFS process with a depth limit of 2 for any node in the frontier, and complete all of those before moving to a depth limit of 3, etc., the algorithm will be optimal.

Comment: What will be the worst case time and space complexity in big O notation?

Comment: @Pete If we treat the memory limit as a constant, the time and space complexity of the initial BFS portion of the algorithm can also be treated as a constant. So, the worst case time and space complexity depend only on the IDS part afterwards. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search for the space complexity (it's `O(d)`). The time complexity depends on implementation again. If you go with the implementation that is not complete and optimal, you get the DFS time complexity. Otherwise, you get the regular IDS time complexity.